# Looking for Mongoose Schema suggestions for individual models

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose-schema

I am in the process of developing a REACT app that would allow a user to find a plant based on their homes environment (long term goal). For my MVP I want to have the user create an account, name their home, add individual rooms with lighting conditions and add plants to each of those rooms. In the event the user does not create any rooms the plants would just sit under their home rather than a specific room by default.

I am struggling on how to design my models and am looking for some suggestions. This will only be my second project on my own so my experience is quite limited.

Currently I have the following models; (attached is a screenshot of each of these models)

plantScheme w/ commonName, scientificName, lightLevel, careLevel, waterReq, etc - This will be seeded with around 100 of the most common household plants to begin with and I intend to use the database to display varying plants on the site whether or not a user is logged in. I also want to link these plants to a specific user when the plant is added to their home.

userSchema w/ username, email, password, home { type: String, required: false, default: 'My Home' } (This begins with where I am open to suggestions. I am not sure if this is the most effective way of establishing the users home), rooms: [ Room.schema ] (pulls from a separate model), plants: [ UserPlant.schema ] (also pulls from a separate model to keep track of plant IDs and room IDs I THINK - haven't tested yet)

userPlantSchema w/ plant_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Plant', required: true } and room_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room', required: false }

and lastly..

roomSchema w/ roomName and lightLevel

If there is a better way of setting up these models and/or keeping track of the users plants I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you for your time.

[screenshot of each model and their established relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtMIx.png)

Comment: I'm still working on a complete answer, but you're adopting a relational approach with a document-oriented DB that is MongoDB. Taking advtantage of nested documents in all the cases where you don't have an N to M relation could be a valid option, try to think about it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and to write a more thorough response. I am calling it a night but will look into nested documents and N to M relationships tomorrow morning!

Comment: @LeonardoViada - If I am understanding correctly you are suggesting I only use a N to M relation between plants and users then use nested documents for the rest of my models (home & rooms)?

Comment: @LeonardoViada Something like this? [new model structure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1acm7LsAKd2_0vbHrtFZDkQvNN0XENRgL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: With nested docs you shouldn't user reference, they're like  an object attribute, simply accessible by dot notation. But your comment is right, you could use reference between plants (that could be possessed by many users) and users (that could possess many plants each). I've had a rugh day but tomorrow I'll post an answer. P.S. It could be more clear and simple thinking of your data structure with E-R diagrams, code is only the last part. See [this model I've made a few days ago](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZgZrhAkD39DH4kCASbv0LLjT1Yed8hBF/view)

Comment: @LeonardoViada - until I understand better on how to create the proper relationships or nested documents for the database using Mongoose (mySQL seemed to come easier), that graph looks like a foreign language to me.